# Proper regex that i couldn't reach

Tags: regex

```
^http(?:s)?:\/\/(?:www\.|events\.)?(?:v\.)?(?:(?:youtube)|(?:youku))\.\w{2,}\/(?:(?:\d{4}\/[^\/]+\/api\/video-files\.php\?\w+=\w+|watch\?(?=[^?]*v=?\-?\w+)(?:[^\s?,^\&amp;?]+)?)|(?:v_show\/id_(?:\w{10,})(?:\.html)?))$
```

I've such a regex that fits according to strings below :

```
http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XODQxOTg0ODg0.html
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n66NLBbQ53w
http://events.youku.com/2014/misc/api/video-files.php?vid=XMjg3MzQ5NTg4
```

But I need to manage the last one to accept all the strings after `'vid='`

for example this needs to be accessible also :

```
http://events.youku.com/2015/misc/api/video-files.php?vid=XMTI2MDEyNzQ0OA==
```

I've tried to add other | for this part such as `\w+=\w+==` but it didn't work...

Anyone please help me to accept the strings after the '=' sign ? \w+ doesn't work i think...

Comment: I think it would be more sane to match the 3 possibilities independently, rather than try to maintain that monstrosity.

Comment: Have you considered to learn regular expressions?

Comment: I can write such a small regexes but sometimes it makes me confused, maybe question is silly and small, but i try to reach a solution.. Sorry for that if it can be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/mR5cU3/1

Here there is:

I juste change your regexp adding `(?:==)?`

^http(?:s)?://(?:www.|events.)?(?:v.)?(?:(?:youtube)|(?:youku)).\w{2,}/(?:(?:\d{4}/[^/]+/api/video-files.php\?\w+=\w+**(?:==)**?|watch\?(?=[^?]*v=?-?\w+)(?:[^\s?,^\&?]+)?)|(?:v_show/id_(?:\w{10,})(?:.html)?))$

Solution :

```
^http(?:s)?:\/\/(?:www\.|events\.)?(?:v\.)?(?:(?:youtube)|(?:youku))\.\w{2,}\/(?:(?:\d{4}\/[^\/]+\/api\/video-files\.php\?\w+=\w+(?:==)?|watch\?(?=[^?]*v=?\-?\w+)(?:[^\s?,^\&amp;?]+)?)|(?:v_show\/id_(?:\w{10,})(?:\.html)?))$
```

Comment: But what i am trying to do that accept whole characters after the 'vid=' so this is just specific to example of '==' i think.

Comment: Then just change (in my example ) 
\w+=\w+(?:==) To **\w+=(?:.*)**

try it here
https://regex101.com/r/mR5cU3/2